# Passing Data Between Views and Controllers

Tags: asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller

I'm working on an application that manages people and their spouses, if married.  Essentially a person will be entered and then from that person I want to be able to add a spouse.  My database schema is like this.  Persons (Person_ID, Name, BirthDate, etc...), Marriages(Marriage_ID, Husband_ID, Wife_ID, Date).

The process is Add a Person then, if married, add spouse.  So I have a Person Controller with an ADD action (get and post).  When Add Spouse is selected in the Details view the AddSpouse Action is called which will create the new person (spouse) and then create the marriage.  MY issue is that I need to pass the PersonID of the original person to the AddSpouse action in order to create a marriage.  What is the best way to do that?

Answer (score 1):

You can pass your personID in ViewData like this :

ViewData["PersonID"] = 1

and recover it in AddSpouse action

`var id = ViewData["PersonID"]`